# Проверка графа на планарность

Tags: алгоритм, графы

> **Определение.** Любой граф, гомеоморфный плоскому, называется планарным. Говорят, что граф *допускает плоскую укладку*, если его можно изобразить как плоский. Например, граф, показанный на рис.1, плоский.
>
> [image: Планарный граф, рис.1]
>   <sup>Рис. 1</sup>
>
> Существуют также и непланарные графы. На рис.2 показаны два таких графа: полный пятивершинник и полный двудольный граф. Для них есть специальные обозначения: K<sub>5</sub> и K<sub>3,3</sub> соответственно.
>
> [image: Непланарные графы, рис.2]
>   <sup>Рис. 2</sup>
>
> **Теорема.** Граф является планарным, если не содержит в себе подграфов, гомеоморфных K<sub>5</sub> или K<sub>3,3</sub>.

Если ли у кого примеры реализации данной проверки?

Comment: Переоформите вопрос, добавьте изображение задачи

Comment: Добавил более подробное описание с картинкой.

Comment: Может быть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854711/how-to-check-if-a-graph-is-a-planar-graph-or-not) с SO поможет?

Answer (score 1):

У меня это расчётная работа) Вот код:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.SourceTree;        
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class start{
    static List<IncedentList> list;
    static int numOfForbidden5 = 0;
    static int numOfForbidden33 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clearList();
        try {
            menu();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("-\\_('_')_/-");
        }
    }

    private static void menu() throws Exception{
        boolean cheaker = true;
        while(cheaker){
            System.out.println("Choose one of the paragraphs:");
            System.out.println("1) Test 1");
            System.out.println("2) Test 2");
            System.out.println("3) Test 3");
            System.out.println("4) Test 4");
            System.out.println("5) Test 5");
            System.out.println("6) Test 6");
            System.out.println("7) Exit\n");
            Scanner vvod = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choose = vvod.nextInt();
            switch(choose){
                case 1:
                    helpForMenu(5, "test1.txt");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    helpForMenu(6, "test2.txt");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    helpForMenu(6, "test3.txt");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    helpForMenu(11, "test4.txt");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    helpForMenu(9, "test5.txt");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    helpForMenu(11, "test6.txt");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println(" End of the program");
                    cheaker = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("-\\_('_')_/-");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void helpForMenu(int n, String nameTest){
        clearList();
        try {
            fill(nameTest);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println();
        }
        show();

        if(isPlanaren(n)){
            System.out.println("Граф изначально планарен!!!");
        }

        boolean oneShowing = true;
        while(!isPlanaren(n)){
            cheakPlanarnost5(n);
            cheakPlanarnost33(n);
            if(oneShowing){
                System.out.print("Фигурок типа 5 : " + numOfForbidden5 + "\n");
                System.out.print("Фигурок типа 3*3 : " + numOfForbidden33 + "\n");
                System.out.print("Минимальное кол-во рёбёр, при удалении которых граф станет планарным : ");
                oneShowing = false;
            }
            String remove = RebroWithPartALotOfFigures();
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).kolReber(); j++){
                    list.get(i).removeRebro(remove);
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                list.get(i).resetAll();
            }
            System.out.print(remove + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void clearList(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new IncedentList("0-oi element exist"));
        numOfForbidden5 = 0;
        numOfForbidden33 = 0;
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void fill(String failname) throws Exception{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(failname));
        IncedentList incedentList = new IncedentList();

        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String value = reader.next();
            if(value.equals("-1")){
                list.add(incedentList);
                incedentList = new IncedentList();
                value = reader.next();
            }
            incedentList.setRebro(value);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    private static void show(){
        System.out.println("Values of incident list");
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(i + ") ");
            IncedentList help = list.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < help.kolReber(); j++){
                System.out.print(help.getRebro(j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private static void cheakPlanarnost5(int n){
        final int m = 5;
        Combinations.getDiapazon(m, n);
        int[] mass = null;

        while((mass = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass)) != null){
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; (j < mass.length) && (j != i); j++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii < list.get(mass[i]).kolReber(); ii++){
                        for(int jj = 0; jj < list.get(mass[j]).kolReber(); jj++){
                            if(IncedentList.compareRebra(list.get(mass[i]).getRebro(ii), list.get(mass[j]).getRebro(jj))){
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count == 10){
                numOfForbidden5++;

                for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; (j < mass.length) && (j != i); j++){
                        for(int ii = 0; ii < list.get(mass[i]).kolReber(); ii++){
                            for(int jj = 0; jj < list.get(mass[j]).kolReber(); jj++){
                                if(IncedentList.compareRebra(list.get(mass[i]).getRebro(ii), list.get(mass[j]).getRebro(jj))){
                                    list.get(mass[i]).incrementNumAsApartOfFigure(list.get(mass[i]).getRebro(ii));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private static void cheakPlanarnost33(int n){
        int counter = 0;
        final int m = 3;
        Combinations.getDiapazon(m, n);
        int count = 0;
        boolean condition = true;

        int[] mass1 = null;
        while((mass1 = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass1)) != null){
            int[] mass2 = null;
            while((mass2 = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass2)) != null){
                if(!cheakComplience(mass1, mass2)){
                    continue;
                }
                count = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++){
                        if(pereborReber(list.get(mass1[i]), list.get(mass2[j]))){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(count == 9){
                    counter++;
                    condition = !condition;
                    if(condition){
                        for(int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++){
                            for(int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++){
                                for(int ii = 0; ii < list.get(mass1[i]).kolReber(); ii++){
                                    for(int jj = 0; jj < list.get(mass2[j]).kolReber(); jj++){
                                        if(IncedentList.compareRebra(list.get(mass1[i]).getRebro(ii), list.get(mass2[j]).getRebro(jj))){
                                            list.get(mass1[i]).incrementNumAsApartOfFigure(list.get(mass1[i]).getRebro(ii));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        numOfForbidden33 = counter/2;
    }

    private static boolean isPlanaren(int n){
        final int m = 3;
        Combinations.getDiapazon(m, n);
        int count = 0;
        boolean condition = true;

        int[] mass1 = null;
        while((mass1 = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass1)) != null){
            int[] mass2 = null;
            while((mass2 = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass2)) != null){
                if(!cheakComplience(mass1, mass2)){
                    continue;
                }
                count = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++){
                        if(pereborReber(list.get(mass1[i]), list.get(mass2[j]))){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(count == 9) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        final int m1 = 5;
        Combinations.getDiapazon(m1, n);
        int[] mass = null;

        while((mass = Combinations.generateCombinations(mass)) != null){
            int count1 = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; (j < mass.length) && (j != i); j++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii < list.get(mass[i]).kolReber(); ii++){
                        for(int jj = 0; jj < list.get(mass[j]).kolReber(); jj++){
                            if(IncedentList.compareRebra(list.get(mass[i]).getRebro(ii), list.get(mass[j]).getRebro(jj))){
                                count1++;
                                //System.out.println("true");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count1 == 10){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean cheakComplience(int mass1[], int[] mass2){
        for(int i = 0; i < mass1.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mass2.length; j++){
                if(mass1[i] == mass2[j]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean pereborReber(IncedentList l1, IncedentList l2){
        for(int j = 0; j < l1.kolReber(); j++){
            for(int jj = 0; jj < l2.kolReber(); jj++){
                if(IncedentList.compareRebra(l1.getRebro(j), l2.getRebro(jj))){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static String RebroWithPartALotOfFigures(){
        int nomber = 0;
        String rebro = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).kolReber(); j++){
                if(list.get(i).getNumAsAPartOfFigure(list.get(i).getRebro(j)) > nomber){
                    nomber = list.get(i).getNumAsAPartOfFigure(list.get(i).getRebro(j));
                    rebro = list.get(i).getRebro(j);
                }
//                System.out.println(list.get(i).getNumAsAPartOfFigure(list.get(i).getRebro(j)));
            }
        }
        return rebro;
    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IncedentList {
    private List<String> rebra = new ArrayList();
    private List<Integer> asAPartOfFigure = new ArrayList<>();

    public void incrementNumAsApartOfFigure(String str){
        for(int i = 0; i < rebra.size(); i++){
            if(compareRebra(str, rebra.get(i))){
                asAPartOfFigure.set(i, (asAPartOfFigure.get(i) + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    public int getNumAsAPartOfFigure(String str){
        for(int i = 0; i < rebra.size(); i++){
            if(compareRebra(str, rebra.get(i))){
                return asAPartOfFigure.get(i);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public void resetAll(){
        for(int i = 0; i < asAPartOfFigure.size(); i++){
            asAPartOfFigure.set(i, 0);
        }
    }

    public void removeRebro(String str){
        for(int i = 0; i < rebra.size(); i++){
            if(compareRebra(str, rebra.get(i))){
                rebra.remove(i);
                asAPartOfFigure.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public IncedentList(String string){
        rebra.add(string);
        asAPartOfFigure.add(0);
    }
    public IncedentList(){};

    public int kolReber(){
        return rebra.size();
    }
    public String getRebro(int i){
        return rebra.get(i);
    }
    public void setRebro(String str){
        rebra.add(str);
        asAPartOfFigure.add(0);
    }

    public static boolean compareRebra(String s1, String s2){
        String half1s1 = "";
        String half2s1 = "";
        String half1s2 = "";
        String half2s2 = "";

        boolean cheaker1 = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
            if(cheaker1 && (s1.charAt(i) != '-')){
                half1s1 += s1.charAt(i);
            }
            if(s1.charAt(i) == '-'){
                cheaker1 = false;
                continue;
            }
            if(!cheaker1){
                half2s1 += s1.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        boolean cheaker2 = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++){
            if(cheaker2 && (s2.charAt(i) != '-')){
                half1s2 += s2.charAt(i);
            }
            if(s2.charAt(i) == '-'){
                cheaker2 = false;
                continue;
            }
            if(!cheaker2){
                half2s2 += s2.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(half1s1 + " " + half2s1 + " \n" + half1s2 + " " + half2s2);

        if(half1s1.equals(half1s2) && half2s1.equals(half2s2)){
            return true;
        }

        if(half1s1.equals(half2s2) && half2s1.equals(half1s2)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


import java.util.Arrays;

class Combinations {
    private static int M = 3;
    private static int N = 5;

    public static void getDiapazon(int m, int n){
        M = m;
        N = n;
    }

    public static int[] generateCombinations(int[] arr) {
        if (arr == null) {
            arr = new int[M];
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                arr[i] = i + 1;
            }
            return arr;
        }
        for (int i = M - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i] < N - M + i + 1) {
                arr[i]++;
                for (int j = i; j < M - 1; j++)
                    arr[j + 1] = arr[j] + 1;
                return arr;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот погружаемые тесты:

```
1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5 -1
2-1 2-3 2-4 2-5 -1
3-1 3-2 3-4 3-5 -1
4-1 4-2 4-3 4-5 -1
5-1 5-2 5-3 5-4 -1

1-2 1-4 1-5 1-6 -1
2-1 2-3 2-4 -1
3-2 3-6 -1
4-1 4-2 4-5 -1
5-1 5-4 -1
6-1 6-3 -1

1-4 1-5 1-6 -1
2-4 2-5 2-6 -1
3-4 3-5 3-6 -1
4-1 4-2 4-3 -1
5-1 5-2 5-3 -1
6-1 6-2 6-3 -1


1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5 -1
2-1 2-3 2-4 2-5 -1
3-1 3-2 3-4 3-5 -1
4-1 4-2 4-3 4-5 -1
5-1 5-2 5-3 5-4 5-11 -1
6-9 6-10 6-11 -1
7-9 7-10 7-11 -1
8-9 8-10 8-11 -1
9-6 9-7 9-8 -1
10-6 10-7 10-8 -1
11-5 11-6 11-7 11-8 -1


1-4 1-5 1-6 -1
2-4 2-5 2-6 -1
3-4 3-5 3-6 3-7 3-8 3-9 -1
4-1 4-2 4-3 -1
5-1 5-2 5-3 -1
6-1 6-2 6-3 6-7 6-8 6-9 -1
7-3 7-6 7-8 7-9 -1
8-3 8-6 8-7 8-9 -1
9-3 9-6 9-7 9-8 -1



1-2 1-3 1-7 1-8 -1
2-1 2-3 2-7 2-8 -1
3-1 3-2 3-4 3-5 3-6 3-7 3-8 -1
4-3 4-5 4-6 4-7 -1
5-3 5-4 5-6 5-7 -1
6-3 6-4 6-5 6-7 6-9 6-10 6-11 -1
7-1 7-2 7-3 7-4 7-5 7-6 7-8 7-9 7-10 7-11 -1
8-1 8-2 8-3 8-7 8-9 8-10 8-11 -1
9-6 9-7 9-8 -1
10-6 10-7 10-8 -1
11-6 11-7 11-8 -1
```

Comment: Неплохо бы словами описать алгоритм

Comment: Генерируем комбинации вершин по типу указаных выше фигур,  и ищем эти комбинации в графе,  инкрементируя счётчик у всех ребер,  в случае если комбинации подошла,  потом удаляем ребра по старшинствву счётчика